# Find the tables that are corrupted in a Database in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

How can I find the corrupted tables in postgresql?
I have to find the table names that are corrupted and I have no idea about that.

Comment: How do you know tables are corrupted?

Comment: If you are afraid of data corruption then create your database cluster with data checksum  enabled

Answer (score 2):

There is no absolutely foolproof way to do that.

The best you can do is

```
pg_dump -f /dev/null dbname
```

This will read all tables and throw an error at the first corruption that causes an error.

There are shortcomings:

- It will not detect corruption that does not cause an error. Enabling data checksums in PostgreSQL will improve that.
- It will not detect index corruption (which can be fixed with `REINDEX`.
- It will only find the first corruption before failing.

  You can exclude that table and start a second run to find other corrupted tables.

Comment: Another problem this will _not_ find is broken foreign keys that reference non-existing rows.